# How I can prioritize mailbox in untyped Actor?

Tags: scala, akka

**Problem:**

Actor process all messages from his mailbox using FIFO strategy.

Let's suppose we want kill an actor sending to him the MyPoisonPill message, actor still handle messages in mailbox until arrive turn of MyPoisonPill.

**Question:**

How I can prioritize messages in actor mailbox?

**UPD:** 
Let's consider A PoisonPill like my own message, because I am not sure that akka's PoisonPill has or not any priority in mailbox.

Comment: I haven't used Akka in a while, but if I remember correctly the PoisonPill is automatically placed first in the mailbox.

Comment: Interesting point, yes I am not sure about it. I would like underline that some my own messages has different priorities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different strategies about how the messages are delivered. You can create a `BoundedPriorityMailbox` to have a priority for your messages.

Other type of mailboxes are given in https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/mailboxes.html#builtin-mailbox-implementations

An example to implement is given in https://blog.knoldus.com/how-to-create-a-priority-based-mailbox-for-an-actor/